# Access DB - Save file location (full) link/path in one field and file name in other field (both or either should be clickable to open the file)

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is my first post and I am new to MS Access with no coding experience. I have a Access Database with a table call Attachments with field as "Saved Path" & "File Name". Both are Hyperlink data type.

Since there is limit of 2GB under MS Access attachments option, I would like to save a link to the file saved outside of MS Access.

What I am looking for is, when a user click on Saved Path it opens a windows dialogue box and user select the file (already created and saved under a network path) and this link/path including file name gets saved under this column. So when required they can refer back to that record and just click on the like to open that file directly from there. And under File Name field the name of the file is copied and saved.

```vb
Private Sub Saved_Path_Click()

    Dim f As Object
    Dim strFullpath As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim varItem As Variant
    
    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    strFullpath = BrowseFile
    
    If f.Show Then
        
        intPos = InStrRev(strFullpath, "\")
               
        
        Me.Saved_Path = "#" & f.SelectedItems(1) & "#"
        Application.FollowHyperlink Me.Saved_Path
   
    End If
    Set f = Nothing    
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, but SO is not a code writing service, it is about helping with code. You should address your question to another fora with a broader target, like _UtterAccess_,  _Bytes.com_, or _Experts Exchange_.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the code which i was playing with, i am adding it on my question now.

Comment: OK. If path and filename are retrieved and passed to the two textboxes (which, I guess, are bound to the fields in the table), what else do you need?

Comment: I just need each (path & file name) saved in the table under respective fields. And when user clicks the link in that record it would open that file, just like what attachments would do.

Comment: If the form is bound to the table and the textboxes to the two fields, the path and file will be saved automatically. To display the full path, concatenate the path and filename to create the valid full path.

Comment: Sorry how do I do that, what should I add to my above code and where?

Comment: You should familiarise yourself with the basic concepts of Access: Assign the table as the _RecordSource_ of the form, then set the _ControlSource_ of the textboxes to the two fields. No code involved.

Comment: You already have code saving data to controls and/or fields. So what happens when you run code - error message, wrong result, nothing? Use FollowHyperlink to open file. @Gustav, why do you say no code is needed? Does seem to be needed to save FileDialog selected data as well as to open file.

Comment: @June7: No code is needed to bind the form and the textboxes.

Comment: Of course, I hadn't followed that train of thought. I assumed form was already bound and open to a record where data is to be saved. Always bad to make assumptions. And I just noticed OP said both fields are hyperlink data type. So this code is likely not properly saving values as hyperlink strings. And FollowHyperlink is not used with hyperlink strings. Hyperlink string is composed of 3 parts separated by # character. Review http://allenbrowne.com/casu-09.html.  I never use Hyperlink type field.

Answer (score 1):

That code is not saving hyperlink string to Hyperlink type field. Access Hyperlink field data is a string composed of 3 parts separated by # character.
**display text # file path\name # any reference within the file**

Could have only one field (Hyperlink or Text) with full path\filename and use code to split the string when you want path or filename part.

If you use a Hyperlink type field, save full file path name formatted as a hyperlink string so it is a clickable hyperlink to open file.
`Me.fieldname = "#" & f.SelectedItems(1) & "#"`
Can extract path part from f.SelectedItems(1) and save to its own Hyperlink field if you want.

If you save path parts, without # characters, to separate normal text fields, options:

VBA FollowHyperlink intrinsic function in Click event procedure to open file

or

calculate a clickable hyperlink string in textbox ControlSource (no VBA).
`="Click to open folder#" & [Saved_Path] & "#"`
`="Click to Open file#" & [Saved_Path] & "\" & [File_Name] & "#"`

Set textbox IsHyperlink property to Yes so text looks like a link.

Comment: Thanks for that but when I use Followhyperlink as "Application.FollowHyperlink Me.Saved_Path" it gives me a Runtime Error 7971: MS Access cannot follow  the hyperlink to `#c:\......#1`.

With regards to using clickable hyperlink string in textbox ControlSource. Currently ControlSource of the textbox is connecting to the "Saved Path" field.

Comment: I have edited the code on my initial post. If i remove the Followhyperlink code then link does get saved by when i click to open the link it again opens the windows dialog box to select the file.

Comment: As I said in my comment under your question, FollowHyperlink cannot be used with the structure as saved in a Hyperlink type field. I have revised answer.

Comment: Of course it will open dialog box because of Click event code. Use a button click event for code opening file dialog to select and save file and have textbox for user to click hyperlink and open file. Set it as Locked so can't edit.

Comment: Correction, Locked textbox won't prevent right click hyperlink menu for Hyperlink type field bound control. If you use Hyperlink type field, might just teach users to use the Hyperlink dialog instead of building VBA for FileDialog. Or disable form shortcut menu. I never use Hyperlink type field.

Comment: Thanks for that I have managed to get it to work. Now the only issue is if I have to delete link under Saved Path field it doesn't automatically delete the file name under File Name field. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Exactly how is value deleted from Saved_Path? User edit? Or a button click?

Comment: User just select the link on that record and press delete.

Comment: Then try in textbox AfterUpdate event procedure: `Me.File_Name = Null`.